# What is the purpose of the catcode stuff in the xcolor package?

Tags: color, sourcecode, catcodes

Right after `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} in v1.0i` of the `xcolor` package, there 
are many fun lines of category codes. Why are these here? What are they doing?

## Snippet from texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty

Version 2016, v.1.0i

```
\expandafter\edef\csname XC@catcodes\endcsname
 {\catcode33 \the\catcode33 % !
  \catcode34 \the\catcode34 % "
  \catcode39 \the\catcode39 % '
  \catcode42 \the\catcode42 % *
  \catcode44 \the\catcode44 % ,
  \catcode45 \the\catcode45 % -
  \catcode46 \the\catcode46 % .
  \catcode47 \the\catcode47 % /
  \catcode58 \the\catcode58 % :
  \catcode59 \the\catcode59 % ;
  \catcode60 \the\catcode60 % <
  \catcode61 \the\catcode61 % =
  \catcode62 \the\catcode62 % >
  \catcode63 \the\catcode63 % ?
  \catcode64 \the\catcode64 % @
  \catcode94 \the\catcode94 % ^
  \catcode96 \the\catcode96 % `
  \catcode`\noexpand\^^A\the\catcode`\^^A\relax}
\catcode64 11 %
\@makeother\! \@makeother\" \@makeother\' \@makeother\* \@makeother\,
\@makeother\- \@makeother\. \@makeother\/ \@makeother\: \@makeother\;
\@makeother\< \@makeother\= \@makeother\> \@makeother\? \@makeother\`
\catcode94 7 %
\catcode`\^^A=14 %
\edef\XC@@{\expandafter\noexpand\csname\string\XC@@\endcsname}
```

Later also

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\!=13 \catcode`\:=13 \catcode`\-=13 \catcode`\+=13
\catcode`\;=13 \catcode`\/=13 \catcode`\"=13 \catcode`\>=13
\gdef\XC@edef#1#2%
 {\begingroup
  \ifnum\catcode`\!=13 \edef!{\string!}\fi
  \ifnum\catcode`\:=13 \edef:{\string:}\fi
  \ifnum\catcode`\-=13 \edef-{\string-}\fi
  \ifnum\catcode`\+=13 \edef+{\string+}\fi
  \ifnum\catcode`\;=13 \edef;{\string;}\fi
  \ifnum\catcode`\"=13 \edef"{\string"}\fi
  \ifnum\catcode`\>=13 \edef>{\string>}\fi
  \edef#1{#2}\@onelevel@sanitize#1\aftergroupdef#1#1}
\gdef\XC@mdef#1#2%
 {\begingroup
  \ifnum\catcode`\/=13 \edef/{\string/}\fi
  \ifnum\catcode`\:=13 \edef:{\string:}\fi
  \edef#1{#2}\@onelevel@sanitize#1\aftergroupdef#1#1}
\endgroup
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\XC@catcodes` macro is an array used to save some category codes at the point of execution of the macro, in order to be able to restore them.

So, under standard settings, the replacement text will begin with

```
\catcode33 12
```

because the standard category code of `!` (ASCII 33) is 12. However, if `babel-french` is in force, we'd get `\catcode33 13`.

The last line is worthy a mention. The `doc` package, used to print documentation contained in `dtx` files makes `^^A` (ASCII 1) into a comment character, so the more complicated

```
\catcode`\noexpand\^^A
```

is used. However it would be much easier to do `\catcode 1 \the\catcode1` like for the previous entries.

Actually, as you can see, the package *does* change the category codes in order to have character tokens with the desired category in replacement text of macros.

What does `\XC@edef` do? It is the package's version of `\edef`, with some twists.

Remember `babel-french` mentioned above? Well `!` is used in the syntax of color specifications. So `\color{red!50}` must work independently of the category code of `!`.

This is solved by doing `\XC@edef` on the argument; the macro opens a group and redefines the active `!` to produce `\string!` so, when the `\edef` is eventually performed, the replacement text will contain a `!` with category code 12 to be passed on for parsing the color specification.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does `babel-french` set ! to category code 13?

Comment: @macmadness86 Because it wants that `!` acts by removing a possible space before it, adding a fixed space and an exclamation mark, according to the typographic rules of French.